# Improving performance of query for generating history

Tags: mysql, performance, query-performance, entity-attribute-value

I have implemented functionality to keep track of changes that are made to items stored in my database. Let's look for example at product licences, which are stored in the table `dp_tech_licence` (primary key `LicenceId`).

Whenever a licence is changed, the changes are stored in the tables `dp_tech_licence_history_mod` (primary key `ModificationId`), `dp_tech_licence_history` (primary key `HistoryId`) and `dp_history` (primary key `CollectionId`). `dp_tech_licence_history_mod` has one row for each property of the licence that is changed, and has a foreign key `HistoryId` referencing `dp_tech_licence_history`. `dp_tech_licence_history` has one row for each licence that is changed, and has a foreign key `CollectionId` referencing `dp_history` and a foreign key `LicenceId` referencing `dp_tech_licence`. `dp_history` has one row for each time one or more changes are applied, and has a foreign key `UserId` referencing `dp_user` (indicating who carried out the changes).

For example when a licence is assigned to a user, `dp_tech_licence.UserId` is changed. This will lead to one new row in each of the tables `dp_tech_licence_history_mod`, `dp_tech_licence_history` and `dp_history`. For the new row in `dp_tech_licence_history_mod` we have the values `Property = 'UserId'` and `Value = '<id>'`, where `<id>` is the user's id.

With all this in place, I want to see the licence history for a specific user. Specifically, I want to know:

1. Every time a licence is assigned to the user (`dp_tech_licence.UserId` is changed to the user's id)
2. Every time a licence is removed from the user (`dp_tech_licence.UserId` is changed from the user's id)

To avoid storing redundant data, only the value a property is changed to is stored in `dp_tech_licence_history_mod`, and not the value the property is changed from. Therefore it is not straight-forward to find out when a licence is removed from the user (point 2 above). I've come up with the following query, where  `<id>` is the user's id:

```
SELECT *
FROM dp_tech_licence_history_mod t1
LEFT JOIN dp_tech_licence_history t2 ON t2.`HistoryId` = t1.`HistoryId`
LEFT JOIN dp_history t3 ON t3.`CollectionId` = t2.`CollectionId`
WHERE t1.`Property` = 'UserId' AND ('<id>' = t1.`Value` OR '<id>' = (
  SELECT t4.`Value`
  FROM dp_tech_licence_history_mod t4
  LEFT JOIN dp_tech_licence_history t5 ON t5.`HistoryId` = t4.`HistoryId`
  LEFT JOIN dp_history t6 ON t6.`CollectionId` = t5.`CollectionId`
  WHERE t4.`Property` = 'UserId' AND t5.`LicenceId` = t2.`LicenceId` AND t6.`ModifiedDate` < t3.`ModifiedDate`
  ORDER BY t6.`ModifiedDate` DESC
  LIMIT 1
))
ORDER BY t3.`ModifiedDate` DESC
```

The condition states that either `dp_tech_licence_history_mod.Value` is the user's id, or that last time `UserId` was changed for the same licence, it was set to the user's id (this means that it is now changed from the user's id to something else).

This query seems to be working fine, but it is really slow! It takes around 1.5 seconds, and `dp_tech_licence_history_mod` has less than 20,000 rows. I think I have added all the indexes I can. Here are the table definitions:

```
CREATE TABLE `dp_tech_licence_history_mod` (
  `ModificationId` bigint(32) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `HistoryId` bigint(32) NOT NULL,
  `LocaleId` bigint(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Property` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `Value` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ModificationId`),
  KEY `dp_tech_licence_history_mod_History` (`HistoryId`),
  KEY `dp_tech_licence_history_mod_Locale` (`LocaleId`),
  KEY `dp_tech_licence_history_mod_Property` (`Property`),
  CONSTRAINT `dp_tech_licence_history_mod_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`HistoryId`) REFERENCES `dp_tech_licence_history` (`HistoryId`),
  CONSTRAINT `dp_tech_licence_history_mod_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`LocaleId`) REFERENCES `dp_locale` (`LocaleId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci

CREATE TABLE `dp_tech_licence_history` (
  `HistoryId` bigint(32) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `CollectionId` bigint(32) NOT NULL,
  `TypeId` bigint(32) NOT NULL,
  `LicenceId` bigint(32) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`HistoryId`),
  KEY `dp_tech_licence_history_Licence` (`LicenceId`),
  KEY `dp_tech_licence_history_Collection` (`CollectionId`),
  KEY `dp_tech_licence_history_Type` (`TypeId`),
  CONSTRAINT `dp_tech_licence_history_Type` FOREIGN KEY (`TypeId`) REFERENCES `dp_history_type` (`TypeId`),
  CONSTRAINT `dp_tech_licence_history_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`LicenceId`) REFERENCES `dp_tech_licence` (`LicenceId`),
  CONSTRAINT `dp_tech_licence_history_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`CollectionId`) REFERENCES `dp_history` (`CollectionId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci

CREATE TABLE `dp_history` (
  `CollectionId` bigint(32) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ModifierId` bigint(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ModifiedDate` datetime NOT NULL,
  `Uri` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  PRIMARY KEY (`CollectionId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 
COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

Here is the result of running `EXPLAIN`.

```
id  select_type           table    type      possible_keys                                                                 key                                     key_len    ref                rows    Extra
1   PRIMARY               t1       ref       dp_tech_licence_history_mod_Property                                          dp_tech_licence_history_mod_Property    766        const              4411    Using index condition
1   PRIMARY               t2       eq_ref    PRIMARY                                                                       PRIMARY                                 8          t1.HistoryId       1       
1   PRIMARY               t3       eq_ref    PRIMARY                                                                       PRIMARY                                 8          t2.CollectionId    1       Using where
2   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY    t5       ref       PRIMARY,dp_tech_licence_history_Licence,dp_tech_licence_history_Collection    dp_tech_licence_history_Licence         8          t2.LicenceId       3       Using temporary; Using filesort
2   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY    t4       ref       dp_tech_licence_history_mod_History,dp_tech_licence_history_mod_Property      dp_tech_licence_history_mod_History     8          t5.HistoryId       1       Using where
2   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY    t6       eq_ref    PRIMARY                                                                       PRIMARY                                 8          t5.CollectionId    1       Using where
```

Does anyone have an idea for how I can improve the performance of my implementation for tracking changes?

Comment: Although avoiding redundancy is noble, it can lead to terrible performance.  Suggest you stop normalizing both `property` and `value`.  Then you will be at an EAV schema, which has merely 'bad' performance.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "stop normalizing both `property` and `value`"?

Comment: Oops, I misread it.  Ignore my comments about normalization.  EAV seems to still be an issue.  Something that might help is improve the indexes; see the related example here: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#speeding_up_wp_postmeta